# Change id values from a SQL database in a pandas dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm currently working on a personal project involving a SQL databases (I'm sort of a beginner). I have a SQLite database that I imported to Python as a pandas dataframe from which want to generate several visualizations (mostly bar graphs).

When I make these graphs, the format of the axis labels are bad and hard to comprehend since what I want to graph are the frequencies of class (that are under a database id as a column header). So, my problem is that I don't know how to change inside my dataframe the id of each column's classes to the corresponding string inside the database; so my axis labels for the class don't be a number but a text.

The dataframe has the following structure, and the classes that I want to make bar graphs with are all the columns that have "id" on it after the "title" column.

[My Pandas Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoQqN.png)

My current plots are resulting in this way (ignore that it is histogram, the image is just to notice how the classes' labels are shown):

[Current Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbisJ.png)

The plots that I want to generate are like this one:

[Desired Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZeDV.png)

The structure of my SQL database is the following:

[Database Code in Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8ZiM.png)

And the way i connected the sqlite database to python is as the following:

```
cnx = sqlite3.connect('MetacriticData.sqlite')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Games WHERE user_score AND meta_score >= 0 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Games WHERE user_score and meta_score = 'TBD' ", cnx)
```

cnx.commit()

The notebook where im working on is the following:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XiGUgZM1ac83qhtJ0W2FHRinRQcgcGsp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide your code, so that we can help you out.

Comment: @ADUBEY Hi, i just edited the post so you can checkout the code (I'm sorry if it's not very good haha), thanks a lot for your time btw!